# In a git post-checkout hook how do you determine if the user branched from HEAD?

Tags: git

I have a post-checkout hook that there's no point running if the user just did:

```
git checkout -b somebranch
```

How do you work out if the previous branch points to the same commit as the new branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git help hooks` reports:

```
   post-checkout
       This hook is invoked when a git checkout is run after having updated the worktree. The hook is given three parameters:
       the ref of the previous HEAD, the ref of the new HEAD (which may or may not have changed), and a flag indicating whether
       the checkout was a branch checkout (changing branches, flag=1) or a file checkout (retrieving a file from the index,
       flag=0). This hook cannot affect the outcome of git checkout.
```

Note the part where it is invoked *after* checkout has already completed, and also the part where it "cannot affect the outcome of `git checkout`".

However, it is passed the refs of the previous and new HEAD, so you could compare those to see if you actually moved, and do stuff (or not) based on that comparison...